# what is the equivalent laravel 8 code for this laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel

```
action('BookingController@edit', ['booking' => $booking->id])
```

I've tried several ways to change the code but couldn't find the laravel 8 equivalent.

Comment: what does it do? or a link with previous docs?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-action) is the old documentation (`7.x`), and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-action) is the new documentation (`8.x`).

So, your new code should be like this:

```php
action([BookingController::class, 'edit'], ['booking' => $booking->id]);
```

Be sure to check out the [great documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) Laravel has instead of asking this nonsense questions please.

Comment: The first thing I did was checking the doc. Thanks for your time to answer the question. But It doesn't work. I tried a lot and asking here was the final decision. Your code does not work either.

Comment: What is the error ? If you are using Laravel 8.x, **THIS** is the way, as the documentation states...